# local svn error: E215004: Authentication failed and interactive prompting is disabled

Tags: linux, ubuntu, svn

I am using svn 1.8 on ubuntu 15.04

When committing to a svn repo I have this error which appears only when using a grunt plugin (which works fine for others https://github.com/stephenharris/grunt-wp-deploy) not if I commit and push to the svn repo manually:

```
Warning: Failed to commit to trunk: Error: Command failed: svn: E215004: Authentication failed and interactive prompting is disabled; see the --force-interactive option
svn: E215004: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.
Authentication failed
```

I tried clearing my keyring files in `.local/share/keyrings` and editing my  `~/.subversion/config` and I have set `password-stores =` to blank as well as  `interactive-conflicts = yes`

but nothing changed really, so I'm not sure what I should do, I think it's a svn configuration issue

Comment: these issues have been then solved on the project mentioned in post